# Webpack 4 and react-router-dom does'nt build correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I bumped into the issue that react-router doesnt work with webpack4. webpack 4 cant build components in  I think my webpack config is something wrong, however I couldn't figure out how to fix my setting.

these are screenshot of the website on webpack-dev-server and the one after build.

[image]

[image]

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist',
    open: true,
    port: Port,
    compress: true,
    publicPath: '/',
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './index.html',
      filename: './index.html',
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
};
```

build website as same as webpack-dev-server's

Comment: use file-loader plugin https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/ , let me know if it works!

Comment: Can you post commands how you run webpack and webpack-dev-server?

Comment: @lavor thank you for your comment. here is my command.
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",

Comment: So there is problem in mode production, for sure can you confirm that running webpack --mode development works correctly?

Comment: @lavor for some reason ''running webpack --mode development "is working...

Comment: @saurssaurav Thank you for your comment. I used file-loader with this config. but still result is same.

const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ['file-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './index.html',
      filename: './index.html',
    }),
  ],
};

Comment: Since I figure out react-router v5 and webpack4 is something wrong,I updated title and comment.

Comment: Can you post some snippet, how are images loaded into your application? Are you using path to them in img element or in css? Or do you import/require them?

Comment: @lavor thank you for your comment. By rewriting set up, I solved the issue.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you please send here your solution? It can help others in a future.

Comment: Simply I misunderstood the concept of prod build. here is the code it works to me for production build.
module.exports = {
  entry: { main: './src/index.js' },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  }

module setting wise, im using same code above.